# How Can I Display Binned Counts in Pandas as a Heat Map with MatPlotLib?

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib

I'm working with a wine data set and noticed that when viewing counts, the larger numbers appear darker and cause a sort of heat map effect.  I was wondering if there's a way to use MatPlotLib to enhance the effect.

```
BINS = [0, 50, 100, 150, 200, 1000]
price_by_points = first150.groupby(['points', pd.cut(first150['price'], BINS)]).size().unstack('price').fillna(0)
```

Produces:

```
price   (0, 50]  (50, 100]  (100, 150]  (150, 200]  (200, 1000]
points                                                         
80        871.0       12.0         0.0         0.0          0.0
81       1444.0       23.0         0.0         0.0          2.0
82       3874.0       55.0         4.0         0.0          0.0
83       5717.0       84.0         3.0         1.0          2.0
84       9861.0      238.0        15.0         4.0          2.0
85      11313.0      262.0        21.0         7.0          1.0
86      13874.0      447.0        26.0         1.0          3.0
87      18097.0      857.0        55.0        12.0          4.0
88      14811.0     1122.0        91.0         7.0          3.0
89      10194.0     1238.0        97.0        13.0         15.0
90      11909.0     2244.0       180.0        45.0         26.0
91       6810.0     2148.0       209.0        28.0         15.0
92       5135.0     2575.0       287.0        74.0         48.0
93       2432.0     2162.0       399.0        98.0        106.0
94       1067.0     1361.0       338.0       100.0        140.0
95        322.0      696.0       205.0        81.0        162.0
96         77.0      262.0       100.0        48.0         78.0
97          9.0      117.0        59.0        29.0         88.0
98          1.0       36.0        29.0        10.0         37.0
99          0.0        8.0         5.0         5.0         21.0
100         0.0        5.0         0.0         4.0         12.0
```

Comment: easiest probably to use `seaborn.heatmap`.  `import seaborn as sns   ;  sns.heatmap(price_by_points)`

Comment: You might want to check the [Creating annotated heatmaps](https://matplotlib.org/gallery/images_contours_and_fields/image_annotated_heatmap.html)  example. If this question is about using pandas within a jupyter notebook, you might also be interested in reading the [pandas style guide](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/style.html).

Answer (score 0):

You can use Matplotlib to generate a heat map and annotate it:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

plt.figure()
heatmap = plt.pcolor(df, cmap='viridis')

# Add text
for y in range(df.shape[0]):
    for x in range(df.shape[1]):
        plt.text(x + 0.5, y + 0.5, '{:.0f}'.format(df.iloc[y, x]),
                 color='w',horizontalalignment='center',
                 verticalalignment='center',)
plt.yticks(np.arange(0.5, len(df.index), 1), df.index)
plt.xticks(np.arange(0.5, len(df.columns), 1), df.columns)
plt.colorbar(heatmap)
plt.ylabel('points')
plt.xlabel('price')
```

[image: Matplotlib heat map]

You can also use seaborn to get an annotated heat map more easily:

```
import seaborn as sns

plt.figure()
sns.heatmap(df, annot=True, fmt='d')
plt.xlabel('Price')
```

[image: Seaborn heat map]

Seaborn does a good job of automatically formatting the text shading so it is visible with the changing background color.